# Unable to select like button in facebook application

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate facebook app,i am unable to click on "like" which is present below each and every posts due to all "like" options has same id/class name.

Please help me. I tried below code its not working:

```
WebElement abc = dr.findElement(By.xpath ("//com.facebook.katana:id/feed_feedback_like_container[@bounds='[0,517][360,637]']"));
abc.click();
```

Comment: that xpath wont work because position of like may change.Even if it changed by one point also it cannot be identified

Answer (score 0):

You can try using index -
your like button is at which index from 0 you can specify as argument to get();

```
WebElement abc = dr.findElements(By.xpath ("//com.facebook.katana:id/feed_feedback_like_container")).get(1);
```

Comment: Hi anuja, I tried above code which you have suggested but its not working.

Comment: Hi anuja, I tried above code which you have suggested but its giving error stating "add cast to method receiver "

Comment: try this  - dr.findElements(By.xpath ("//com.facebook.katana:id/feed_feedback_like_container")).get(1).click() ;

Comment: Hi anuja still i am facing problem     .get(1).click(); i dont see any method like .get(1)

Comment: Only these options are available  1.getAttribute(arg0) 2.getclass() 3.getCssValue(arg0) 4.getLocation() 5.getRect() 6.getScreenshotAs(arg0) 7.getSize(). 8.getTagName(). 9.getText()

Comment: if you use findElements() instead of findElement() then you will see get() method.